# Laravel Model issue

Tags: laravel-4

I am learning laravel . I want to know that if I can use query builder inside the laravel model that extends Eloquent or not . I read about MVC that Model should be fat and controllers must be slim. But when I am trying to do something using mvc such as inserting post into db or extracting posts from database my controllers hold most of the queries .

Comment: I think it's time you should expand your reading beyond MVC. As a starting point I'd advise that you take a look at beginners lessons on laracasts.com and participate in forum discussions.

Answer (score 0):

my personal opinion in Laravel. According to what I see during this two years learning models controllers or routes correctly.

First. practice in routes, doing some code. you could find some examples in Laravel.com.

Secondly. try to get into refactoring. which means ... that you have to improve your code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping as much logic as possible in your models is a really good practice to get into because it keeps the rules in a single place. For example, if you have a blog posts model, rather than querying the model in your controller for archived posts you can define an archived attribute in your model like this:

```
public function scopeArchived($query) {
  return $query->where('archived', true);
}
```

After which you can simple query for `App\Post::archived()->get()`. If the logic for what defines an "archived post" changes later, you can change it in one place. It also means you can chain your filters very easily. If, for example, you have an attribute to filter by author:

```
public function scopeWrittenBy($query, User $user) {
  return $query->where('author', $user->id);
}
```

...you can chain these together in your controller with:

```
$user = App\User::first();
$archived_user_posts = App\Post::archived()->writtenBy($user)->get();
```